# Windows 2003 server: can't join domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I originally tried to rejoin a computer to a network which led to a "cannot find domain" error.  The username/password box don't even come up.

Some tests I ran:
I can ping the server name. 
I can't ping the server's FQD.N 
I can't ping the domain name `domain1.local`.
nslookup can't find the domain.

So I go to the DNS and run netdiag.exe and gives me this error:

```
DNS test . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Failed
          [WARNING] Cannot find a primary authoritative DNS server for the name
            'stmartinsrv.stmartin.local.'. [RCODE_SERVER_FAILURE]
            The name 'srv.domain1.local.' may not be registered in DNS.

    [WARNING] The DNS entries for this DC are not registered correctly on DNS se
rver '68.94.156.1'. Please wait for 30 minutes for DNS server replication.
    [WARNING] The DNS entries for this DC are not registered correctly on DNS se
rver '68.94.157.1'. Please wait for 30 minutes for DNS server replication.
    [FATAL] No DNS servers have the DNS records for this DC registered.


Redir and Browser test . . . . . . : Passed
    List of NetBt transports currently bound to the Redir
        NetBT_Tcpip_{04BB0F6B-06AE-4D60-80C8-2A7A24C1D87B}
    The redir is bound to 1 NetBt transport.

    List of NetBt transports currently bound to the browser
        NetBT_Tcpip_{04BB0F6B-06AE-4D60-80C8-2A7A24C1D87B}
    The browser is bound to 1 NetBt transport.
```

Then running dcdiag,

```
C:\Program Files\Support Tools>dcdiag

Domain Controller Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SRV
      Starting test: Connectivity
         The host 1c99f63c-49ec-40db-b3d3-6265c00fbd3e._msdcs.domain1.local cou
ld not be resolved to an
         IP address.  Check the DNS server, DHCP, server name, etc
         Although the Guid DNS name
         (1c99f63c-49ec-40db-b3d3-6265c00fbd3e._msdcs.domain1.local) couldn't
         be resolved, the server name (srv.domain1.local) resolved to
         the IP address (192.168.1.21) and was pingable.  Check that the IP
         address is registered correctly with the DNS server.
         ......................... SRV failed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

       Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SRV
          Skipping all tests, because server SRV is
          not responding to directory service requests

       Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
          Starting test: CrossRefValidation
             ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

          Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
             ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

       Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
          Starting test: CrossRefValidation
             ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

          Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
             ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

       Running partition tests on : Schema
          Starting test: CrossRefValidation
             ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
          Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
             ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom

       Running partition tests on : Configuration
          Starting test: CrossRefValidation
             ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
          Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
             ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom

       Running partition tests on : domain1
          Starting test: CrossRefValidation
             ......................... domain1 passed test CrossRefValidation
          Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
             ......................... domain1 passed test CheckSDRefDom

       Running enterprise tests on : domain1.local
          Starting test: Intersite
             ......................... domain1.local passed test Intersite
          Starting test: FsmoCheck
             ......................... domain1.local passed test FsmoCheck
```

From previous postings, I've tried adding the domain suffix to the NIC IP properties to both the client machine and the domain controller server which didn't help.

Note: there is only one NIC on the server.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I partially fixed the problem by removing the ISP DNS IP addresses from the local NIC card and just added the SRV server IP address (192.168.x.x) to the DNS tab of the IP properties of the NIC card.  Now when I run nslookup on SRV, it resolves to the domain name locally.
When I run nslookup on `domain1.local`, it resolves to the domain to the server IP address locally on the server.  However when I try to do the same thing on the client machine, I still receive an unknown host response when I attempt to run `nslookup domain1.local` and the FQDN.

**UPDATE 2**: I also manually set the DNS IP address on the client's NIC IP settings in the DNS tab which didn't work either. Yet I can still ping domain controller/DNS server

On the client when I run ipconfig and nslookup:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ping domain1.local
Ping request could not find host domain1.local. Please check the name and try a
gain.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : CLIENT02
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : domain1.local

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain1.local
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82562V-2 10/100 Network Con
nection
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1A-A0-8B-94-87
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.107
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.21
                                            192.168.0.1
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, April 11, 2010 8:45:15 PM
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, April 18, 2010 7:24:15 PM

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>nslookup
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Can't find server name for address 192.168.1.21: Timed out
*** Can't find server name for address 192.168.0.1: Non-existent domain
*** Default servers are not available
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.21

> server 192.168.1.21
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Default Server:  [192.168.1.21]
Address:  192.168.1.21

>
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>nslookup
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Can't find server name for address 192.168.1.21: Timed out
*** Can't find server name for address 192.168.0.1: Non-existent domain
*** Default servers are not available
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.21

> ls domain1.local
ls: connect: No error
*** Can't list domain domain1.local: Unspecified error
>
```

and then I ran netdiag /d:domain1.local

```
...................................

    Computer Name: CLIENT02
    DNS Host Name: CLIENT02
    System info : Windows 2000 Professional (Build 2600)
    Processor : x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
    List of installed hotfixes :
        KB835221WXP
        KB888111WXPSP2
        KB893803v2
        Q147222


Netcard queries test . . . . . . . : Passed
    GetStats failed for 'Intel(R) 82562V-2 10/100 Network Connection - AGN Filter Interface'. [ERROR_GEN_FAILURE]


Per interface results:

    Adapter : Local Area Connection

        Netcard queries test . . . : Passed

        Host Name. . . . . . . . . : CLIENT02.domain1.local
        IP Address . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.107
        Subnet Mask. . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway. . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        Dns Servers. . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.21
                                     192.168.0.1


        AutoConfiguration results. . . . . . : Passed

        Default gateway test . . . : Passed

        NetBT name test. . . . . . : Passed
        [WARNING] At least one of the <00> 'WorkStation Service', <03> 'Messenger Service', <20> 'WINS' names is missing.

        WINS service test. . . . . : Skipped
            There are no WINS servers configured for this interface.

        Ipx configration
            Network Number . . . . : 00000000
            Node . . . . . . . . . : 001aa08b9487
            Frame type . . . . . . : 802.2



    Adapter : IPX Internal Interface

        Netcard queries test . . . : Passed

        Ipx configration
            Network Number . . . . : 00000000
            Node . . . . . . . . . : 000000000001
            Frame type . . . . . . : Ethernet II



    Adapter : IpxLoopbackAdapter

        Netcard queries test . . . : Passed

        Ipx configration
            Network Number . . . . : 1234cdef
            Node . . . . . . . . . : 000000000002
            Frame type . . . . . . : 802.2



    Adapter : NDISWANIPX

        Netcard queries test . . . : Passed

        Ipx configration
            Network Number . . . . : 00000000
            Node . . . . . . . . . : f6f220524153
            Frame type . . . . . . : Ethernet II




Global results:


Domain membership test . . . . . . : Passed
    Dns domain name is not specified.
    Dns forest name is not specified.


NetBT transports test. . . . . . . : Passed
    List of NetBt transports currently configured:
        NetBT_Tcpip_{3DF46308-913D-4B62-8F6A-AC1E076E3864}
    1 NetBt transport currently configured.


Autonet address test . . . . . . . : Passed


IP loopback ping test. . . . . . . : Passed


Default gateway test . . . . . . . : Passed


NetBT name test. . . . . . . . . . : Passed
    [WARNING] You don't have a single interface with the <00> 'WorkStation Service', <03> 'Messenger Service', <20> 'WINS' names defined.


Winsock test . . . . . . . . . . . : Passed


DNS test . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Passed


Redir and Browser test . . . . . . : Passed
    List of NetBt transports currently bound to the Redir
        NetBT_Tcpip_{3DF46308-913D-4B62-8F6A-AC1E076E3864}
    The redir is bound to 1 NetBt transport.

    List of NetBt transports currently bound to the browser
        NetBT_Tcpip_{3DF46308-913D-4B62-8F6A-AC1E076E3864}
    The browser is bound to 1 NetBt transport.


DC discovery test. . . . . . . . . : Failed

 This computer cannot be joined to the [domain1.local] domain because of one of the
following reasons.

1. The DNS SRV record for [domain1.local] is not registered in DNS; or

2. A zone from the following list of DNS zones does not include delegation
to its child zone.

Such zones can include [_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain1.local], and root zone.

Ask your network/DNS administrator to perform the following actions: To
find out why the SRV record for [domain1.local, local] is not registered in the DNS,
run the dcdiag command prompt tool with the command RegisterInDNS on the
domain controller that did not perform the registration.
        [FATAL] Cannot find DC in domain 'domain1.local'. [ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN]


DC list test . . . . . . . . . . . : Failed
        'domain1.local': Cannot find DC to get DC list from [test skipped].


Trust relationship test. . . . . . : Skipped


Kerberos test. . . . . . . . . . . : Skipped


LDAP test. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Failed
    Cannot find DC to run LDAP tests on. The error occurred was: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.



 This computer cannot be joined to the [domain1.local] domain because of one of the
following reasons.

1. The DNS SRV record for [domain1.local] is not registered in DNS; or

2. A zone from the following list of DNS zones does not include delegation
to its child zone.

Such zones can include [_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain1.local], and root zone.

Ask your network/DNS administrator to perform the following actions: To
find out why the SRV record for [domain1.local, local] is not registered in the DNS,
run the dcdiag command prompt tool with the command RegisterInDNS on the
domain controller that did not perform the registration.
        [WARNING] Cannot find DC in domain 'domain1.local'. [ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN]


Bindings test. . . . . . . . . . . : Passed


WAN configuration test . . . . . . : Skipped
    No active remote access connections.


Modem diagnostics test . . . . . . : Passed


Netware configuration
    You are not logged in to your preferred server .
    Netware User Name. . . . . . . :
    Netware Server Name. . . . . . :
    Netware Tree Name. . . . . . . :
    Netware Workstation Context. . :

IP Security test . . . . . . . . . : Passed
    Service status  is: Started
    Service startup is: Automatic
    IPSec service is available, but no policy is assigned or active
    Note: run "ipseccmd /?" for more detailed information


The command completed successfully
```

On the server SRV

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.21
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : srv
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : domain1.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : domain1.local

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-21-70-16-F5-6E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.21
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.21

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>nslookup domain1.local
Server:  srv.domain1.local
Address:  192.168.1.21

Name:    domain1.local
Address:  192.168.1.21


C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>nslookup
Default Server:  srv.domain1.local
Address:  192.168.1.21

> server 192.168.1.21
Default Server:  srv.domain1.local
Address:  192.168.1.21

> ls domain1.local
[srv.domain1.local]
*** Can't list domain domain1.local: Query refused
The DNS server refused to transfer the zone domain1.local to your computer. If
this
is incorrect, check the zone transfer security settings for domain1.local on th
e DNS
server at IP address 192.168.1.21.
> ^C
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ping domain1.local

Pinging domain1.local [192.168.1.21] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.1.21: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.21: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.21:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
Control-C
^C
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>
```

Then running dcdiag.exe:

Domain Controller Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SRV
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... SRV passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

```
   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SRV
      Starting test: Replications
         ......................... SRV passed test Replications
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... SRV passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         ......................... SRV passed test NetLogons
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... SRV passed test Advertising
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... SRV passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... SRV passed test RidManager
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... SRV passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: Services
         ......................... SRV passed test Services
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... SRV passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: frssysvol
         ......................... SRV passed test frssysvol
      Starting test: frsevent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the          SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause          Group Policy problems.
         ......................... SRV failed test frsevent
      Starting test: kccevent
         ......................... SRV passed test kccevent
      Starting test: systemlog
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC0002715
            Time Generated: 04/12/2010   13:35:18
            (Event String could not be retrieved)
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0xC0001B7A
            Time Generated: 04/12/2010   13:45:27
            (Event String could not be retrieved)
         ......................... SRV failed test systemlog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... SRV passed test VerifyReferences

   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : stmartin
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... stmartin passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... stmartin passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running enterprise tests on : domain1.local
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... domain1.local passed test Intersite
      Starting test: FsmoCheck
         ......................... domain1.local passed test FsmoCheck
```

and then netdiag /d:domain1.local:

```
....................................

    Computer Name: SRV
    DNS Host Name: SRV.domain1.local
    System info : Microsoft Windows Server 2003 (Build 3790)
    Processor : x86 Family 15 Model 127 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD
    List of installed hotfixes :
        KB923561
        KB924667-v2
        KB925398_WMP64
        KB925902-v2
        KB927891
        KB929123
        KB930178
        KB932168
        KB933854
        KB938127
        KB941569
        KB943055
        KB943460
        KB944338-v2
        KB944653
        KB945553
        KB946026
        KB948496
        KB950762
        KB950974
        KB951066
        KB951748
        KB952004
        KB952069
        KB952954
        KB953298
        KB954155
        KB954550-v5
        KB955069
        KB955759
        KB956572
        KB956802
        KB956803
        KB956844
        KB957097
        KB958469
        KB958644
        KB958687
        KB958869
        KB959426
        KB960225
        KB960803
        KB960859
        KB961063
        KB961118
        KB961501
        KB967715
        KB967723
        KB968389
        KB968816
        KB969059
        KB969947
        KB970238
        KB970430
        KB971032
        KB971486
        KB971557
        KB971633
        KB971657
        KB971737
        KB971961
        KB972270
        KB973037
        KB973354
        KB973507
        KB973525
        KB973540
        KB973687
        KB973815
        KB973869
        KB973904
        KB974112
        KB974318
        KB974392
        KB974571
        KB975025
        KB975467
        KB976098-v2
        KB976325
        KB978207
        Q147222


Netcard queries test . . . . . . . : Passed
    [WARNING] The net card 'RAS Async Adapter' may not be working because it has not received any packets.



Per interface results:

    Adapter : Local Area Connection 2

        Netcard queries test . . . : Passed

        Host Name. . . . . . . . . : SRV
        IP Address . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.21
        Subnet Mask. . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway. . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        Dns Servers. . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.21


        AutoConfiguration results. . . . . . : Passed

        Default gateway test . . . : Passed

        NetBT name test. . . . . . : Passed
        [WARNING] At least one of the <00> 'WorkStation Service', <03> 'Messenger Service', <20> 'WINS' names is missing.
            No remote names have been found.

        WINS service test. . . . . : Skipped
            There are no WINS servers configured for this interface.


Global results:


Domain membership test . . . . . . : Passed


NetBT transports test. . . . . . . : Passed
    List of NetBt transports currently configured:
        NetBT_Tcpip_{04BB0F6B-06AE-4D60-80C8-2A7A24C1D87B}
    1 NetBt transport currently configured.


Autonet address test . . . . . . . : Passed


IP loopback ping test. . . . . . . : Passed


Default gateway test . . . . . . . : Passed


NetBT name test. . . . . . . . . . : Passed
    [WARNING] You don't have a single interface with the <00> 'WorkStation Service', <03> 'Messenger Service', <20> 'WINS' names defined.


Winsock test . . . . . . . . . . . : Passed


DNS test . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Passed
    PASS - All the DNS entries for DC are registered on DNS server '192.168.1.21' and other DCs also have some of the names registered.


Redir and Browser test . . . . . . : Passed
    List of NetBt transports currently bound to the Redir
        NetBT_Tcpip_{04BB0F6B-06AE-4D60-80C8-2A7A24C1D87B}
    The redir is bound to 1 NetBt transport.

    List of NetBt transports currently bound to the browser
        NetBT_Tcpip_{04BB0F6B-06AE-4D60-80C8-2A7A24C1D87B}
    The browser is bound to 1 NetBt transport.


DC discovery test. . . . . . . . . : Passed


DC list test . . . . . . . . . . . : Passed


Trust relationship test. . . . . . : Skipped


Kerberos test. . . . . . . . . . . : Passed


LDAP test. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Passed


Bindings test. . . . . . . . . . . : Passed


WAN configuration test . . . . . . : Skipped
    No active remote access connections.


Modem diagnostics test . . . . . . : Passed

IP Security test . . . . . . . . . : Skipped

    Note: run "netsh ipsec dynamic show /?" for more detailed information


The command completed successfully
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll find the key may lie here:

`[WARNING] The DNS entries for this DC are not registered correctly on DNS server '68.94.156.1'. Please wait for 30 minutes for DNS server replication.`

Is that your public ISP DNS server? If so, then this is the wrong DNS server to be using.

1. There should be a DNS server somewhere in your AD (It's usually on your Domain Controller if you only have one)
2. The Domain Controller should have its DNS pointing to itself
3. The client machines should have their DNS pointing to the IP address of your internal DNS server (e.g. your domain controller)

Your ISP's DNS server will not be used inside a normal AD network.

Edit: I just saw your update. You must have posted it while I was writing my answer. Ensure that Step 3 has been implemented as well.

Comment: I set the client's dns ip address located in the nic ip settings and the same result occurred.  unable to find fqdn and pinging domain1.local didn't work as well.  It was able to surf the web though.

Comment: @phill - When you run `nslookup` it should give you a `default server` and `address` - do these match your **internal** DNS server?

Comment: it does give me the default server ip address when i run nslookup.. thanks

Comment: @Phill, I'm not sure what you mean by "default server ip address" - do you mean that it IS pointing to your internal DNS (e.g. `192.168.0.1`), or it is pointing elsewhere?

Comment: sorry about that, the network only has one DC with the DNS/AD on it and it returns 192.168.1.21 however it doesn't return its corresponding hostname

Comment: Not returning the hostname isn't always a bad thing, it just means that the DNS server does not have a PTR record for the IP address, which should not affect this functionality in any way. If the nslookup on the client is displaying the internal DNS, but it can't lookup your domain name, then I'd say there's much bigger issues at play. Can the DNS on the client machine resolve ANYTHING with `nslookup`?

Comment: it is unable to resolve anything locally, however the machine is able to browse the internet.

Comment: Is this just a single machine, no one else is having these problems? Some malware can play tricks with the dns client...

Comment: the other clients are unable to resolve the dns hostname and domain name as well. I didn't want to risk trying to disjoin the other workstations from the network.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the event logs on your DC? Do you allow unsecure DNS updates on your AD zone?

Comment: It is set to "secure only" updates.  I will post any error messages above.

Answer (score 0):

You said 'rejoin' the machine. Are the old DNS records for the system still in the zone? Do the current domain controllers only have their own IP's listed for their DNS servers? Did you remove the old computer account before you attempted to rejoin? Is the name of the server the same as it was before you unjoined? You may have some stale information in AD if so. Check all the SRV records in DNS, make sure they resolve to what they should resolve to. If you see any 'Unknown Accounts' on the ACL's for any of those records, delete them and run 'ipconfig /registerdns' from the machine that should hold them.

Comment: I have deleted all entires in the dns as well as in active directory under the computers object.  This didn't seem to help either.  I also went to the client and ran 'ipconfig /registerdns' and still got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The firewall on the nic got turned on for some reason.  Once it was disabled, everything worked just fine.  Go figure.